# Visual representation (error?) of part stack for e4 oxygen

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, e4, eclipse-oxygen

We recently updated our e4 target platform to oxygen.
Now, we are seeing strange lines on each part stack.

Does anybody know why this could be happening and how we can get a "clean" rendering?

[image]

Comment: I have not seen this on any of my e4 apps using Oxygen or Photon. So you need to narrow this down and show us a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by the css styling. This is an example of a setting which causes this:

```
.MPartStack {
    swt-tab-renderer: url('bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.CTabRendering');
    swt-unselected-tabs-color: radial #ffffff #ffffff 60%;
    swt-shadow-visible: true;
}
```

Either of the following corrects the problem:

add "100%":

```
swt-unselected-tabs-color: radial #ffffff #ffffff 60% 100%;
```

set from true to false:

```
swt-shadow-visible: false;
```